# RAILS_ROOT_VIEW_PATH Constant, like RAILS_ROOT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, constants

Is there an answer to the following SAT-style analogy?

```
. : RAILS_ROOT :: ./app/views : ???
```

I.e., is there a constant in Rails for the path `app/views`?

The reason I'm asking is because from `app/models/notifier.rb`, I'm trying to render the body of an email with a file:

```
  def notify_fact_act(user, domain, filename)
    subject "Email with multipart/alternative & attachment"
    recipients user.email
    from "rails@example.com"
    content_type "multipart/mixed"

    file = File.join(view_paths.last, mailer_name, @template+'.text.')
    body = {:user => user, :domain => domain}
    part :content_type => "multipart/alternative" do |p|
      p.part :content_type => "text/plain",
        :body => render(:file => file + "plain.erb", :body => body)
      p.part :content_type => "text/html",
        :body => render(:file => file + "html.erb", :body => body)
    end

    attachment :content_type => "application/pdf",
      :body => File.read(filename),
      :filename => File.basename(filename)
  end
```

Note: the reason I'm doing explicit template rendering is that the [ActionMailer::Base documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base) states, "Implicit template rendering is not performed if any attachments or parts have been added to the email," and I'm adding a PDF attachment.

Also, from the debugger, I find that `view_paths.last` gives me what I want, but it seems variable. I want something constant that I know will work every time.

Also, from the debugger, I can type `p instance_variables` & `p.local_variables`, but I don't see a method (in the output of `p puts methods.sort`) for printing out the available constants. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: don't do that.

That's like asking for the single path in the `PATH` environment variable when in reality there are probably many paths in it. You should be using Rails' built-in [`render`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) function to do anything that needs to deal with view files. Carefully consider why you need to know that path. Are you sure you do, or can you just use `render`?

Comment: I am using `render` but from a `model`. See the updates I made to the question.

Comment: I'm almost certain there's a better way to do that, but I'm not sure what it is at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call the model method from a controller and pass the path obtained through `controller_path` or `params[:controller]`.